# Regex Capturing groups from HTML string in .NET

Tags: c#, html, .net, regex, grouping

Looking to capture from html into groups as Header, Name and Val

The HTML can vary, but this is how it would typically look

```
<div>
   <h5>Header 1</h5>
      <strong>Name1</strong>
          &nbsp;
          Value 1 <br>
      <strong>Name2</strong>
          &nbsp;
          Value 2 <br>
   <div>
   <h5>Header 2</h5>
      <strong>Name1</strong>
          &nbsp;
          Value 1 <br>
          Value 1 continued
      <strong>Name2</strong>
          &nbsp;
          Value 2 <br>
   <h5>Header 3</h5>
      <strong>Name1</strong>
          &nbsp;
          Value 1 <br>
          Value 1 continued
      <strong>Name2</strong>
          &nbsp;
          Value 2 <br>
   <br>
   </div>
</div>
```

This what I started using, but this relies that nothing is after the <br>

```
string pattern = "((<h5>(?<Header>.*?)<\\/h5>)|(<strong>(?<Name>.*?)<\\/strong>)|(&nbsp;(?<Val>.*?)<br>))
```

Comment: There are [much](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngleSharp/) [better](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) [tools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery/) available for this job, don't use regex.

Comment: [Obligatory link on Regex and HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1958365).

Comment: I recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1945631

Comment: I'd stress this part: *The HTML can vary, but this is how it would typically look*. Are you interested in an HTML parser based solution? I hope you should be, sincewith the parser, you will be able to do 2 things safely: extract  the text and convert entities to literals.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski CsQuery looks like a great tool for this. Can you help me how I would select the above groups or a link with more detailed examples? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Remove the concurrences of "br" tag from the input, voila. `str.Replace("<br>","")`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I Changed the pattern to

```
string pattern = "(((?<=<h5>)(?<Header>.*?)(?=<\\/h5>))|((?<=<strong>)(?<Name>.*?)(?=<\\/strong>))|((?<=<\\/strong>)(?<Val>.*?)((?=<h5>)|(?=<strong>)|(?=<\\/div>))))";
```

Seems to be working. If you have a cleaner better answer, I will set your answer as the correct one.

Comment: `if you have a cleaner better answer` Of course. Use HtmlAgilityPack instead of maintaining this monster string :)

Comment: @Eser please write an answer with code using HTMLAgilityPack .